# Find block name without template hints for block whitelist

Tags: ce-1.9.2.2

I'm getting battered by the new block whitelist, because I don't actually know what my blocks are called.

Is there a reliable method of finding block names without template hints?

Edit: I should say, I don't have an explicit block in any XML files that I can find.

Comment: [Here's a useful link](https://gordonlesti.com/how-to-find-the-name-in-layout-of-a-block-in-magento/) where Gordon Lesti explains how to find the name of a block in Magento. Please note that if you find the block `name="brands_brands"` in the layout .xml file then you should add `brands/brands` to the white list

Comment: Than you, I'll have a read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of **Patch SUPEE-7405** and **Magento CE 1.9.2.3** there is a new core feature to easily identify blocks that are missing from the whitelist.

The Magento Team has updated the `blockDirective($construction)` function in

```
app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template/Filter.php
```

It now looks like this:

```
/**
 * Retrieve Block html directive
 *
 * @param array $construction
 * @return string
 */
public function blockDirective($construction)
{
    $skipParams = array('type', 'id', 'output');
    $blockParameters = $this->_getIncludeParameters($construction[2]);
    $layout = Mage::app()->getLayout();
    $block = null;

    if (isset($blockParameters['type'])) {
        if ($this->_permissionBlock->isTypeAllowed($blockParameters['type'])) {
            $type = $blockParameters['type'];
            $block = $layout->createBlock($type, null, $blockParameters);
        } else {
            Mage::log('Security problem: ' . $blockParameters['type'] . ' has not been whitelisted.');
        }
    } elseif (isset($blockParameters['id'])) {
        $block = $layout->createBlock('cms/block');
        if ($block) {
            $block->setBlockId($blockParameters['id']);
        }
    }

    if ($block) {
        $block->setBlockParams($blockParameters);
        foreach ($blockParameters as $k => $v) {
            if (in_array($k, $skipParams)) {
                continue;
            }
            $block->setDataUsingMethod($k, $v);
        }
    } else {
        return '';
    }

    if (isset($blockParameters['output'])) {
        $method = $blockParameters['output'];
    }
    if (!isset($method) || !is_string($method) || !method_exists($block, $method)) {
        $method = 'toHtml';
    }
    return $block->$method();
}
```

> **Notice the new**
>
> `Mage::log('Security problem: ' . $blockParameters['type'] . ' has not
>   been whitelisted.');`

If a block is missing from the whitelist then the system will detect it and print an error including the missing blocks name in the `system.log` file located in

```
[your magento install dir]/var/log/
```

So all you have to do now is to apply Patch SUPEE-7405 (or upgrade to Magento CE 1.9.2.3), enable logging from your Admin Panel, navigate through all types of pages in your frontend and watch the `system.log` file for any missing block names.

Great job by the Magento Team!